# Linux bash multithread/process small jobs

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, multiprocessing

I have a script that runs some data processing command 10K times.

```
foreach f (folderName/input*.txt)
  mycmd $f
end
```

I have timed the runtime for each "mycmd $f" to be 0.25 secs.
With 10K runs, it adds up to be more than 1 hr.
I'm running it on a 16 cores nehalem. 
It's a huge waste to not run on the remaining 15 cores.

I have tried & with sleep, somehow the script just dies with a warning or error around 3900 iterations, see below. The shorter the sleep, that faster it dies.

```
foreach f (folderName/input*.txt)
  mycmd $f & ; sleep 0.1
end
```

There has got to be a better way.
Note: I would prefer shell script solutions, let's not wander into C/C++ land.

Thanks

Regards

Comment: What's the error?   Also, you'll use all 16 cores, unless you've set the affinity somehow in a custom fashion.   The slowness is likely in whatever [mycmd] is actually doing.

Comment: It's possible you are spawning too many processes. The shorter the sleep time, the more processes you'll start before any of them can complete.

Comment: That looks like PHP or Perl rather than Bash. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipe the list of files to

```
xargs -n 1 -P 16 mycmd
```

For example:

```
echo folderName/input*.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 16 mycmd
```

Comment: Using `ls` and `xargs` together can cause problems (e.g. if an file has spaces in its name): `find folderName -maxdepth 1 -name 'input*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 ...`  is safer.

Comment: Edited; replaced `ls` with `echo`. Could still be improved, I'm sure.

Comment: @tripleee, `echo` is no better than `ls`. There is still exactly the same issue with spaces in file names.

Comment: Yeah, it merely avoids the problems specific to `ls` (like recursing into subdirectories, which of course you can fix with `ls -d` ... or LSD - sorry, couldn't resist) and saves a process, provided `echo` is built into your shell.

Comment: A bit clarification, the original code was csh not bash, my mind just slipped. Also my command took 3 args as input. So I end up using xargs -n 3 -P 16 mycmd

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other solutions possible using one of the following applications:

[xjobs](http://www.maier-komor.de/xjobs.html)

[Parallel](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~er258/code/parallel.html)

[PPSS - Parallel Processing Shell Script](http://code.google.com/p/ppss/)

[runpar.sh](http://lug.fh-swf.de/shell/)

Answer (score 0):

Submit the jobs with `batch`; that should fix load balancing and resource starvation issues.

```
for f in folderName/input.*; do
    batch <<____HERE
        mycmd "$f"
____HERE
done
```

(Not 100% sure whether the quotes are correct and/or useful.)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel mycmd ::: folderName/input*.txt
```

From: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

= Full installation =

Full installation of GNU Parallel is as simple as:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

If you are not root you can add ~/bin to your path and install in
~/bin and ~/share:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install
```

Or if your system lacks 'make' you can simply copy src/parallel
src/sem src/niceload src/sql to a dir in your path.

= Minimal installation =

If you just need parallel and do not have 'make' installed (maybe the
system is old or Microsoft Windows):

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
mv parallel sem dir-in-your-$PATH/bin/
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1